# Copyright a Land Feature?

Tags: united-states, copyright, real-property, new-mexico

This sign is posted on private property in New Mexico, USA at:
35.47212, -106.15719

[image]

> COPYRIGHT NOTICE Photos and videos taken of Lone Butte Mountain may
> not be directly or indirectly published, reproduced, stored, modified,
> published, copied, transmitted, sold, projected, redistributed and
> used in any way without the permission of the owner, to avoid
> copyright infringement.

Issues/Questions:

1. Just a comment. Given the poor writing, this sign does not appear to have been written by an attorney.
2. Is it legally valid to copyright a land feature?
3. Does this make it illegal for me to photograph (and publish) a photo taken while I'm standing on public land (in this case County Road 45)
4. Same as 2, but supposed I own the land on the other side of the road and take the photo
5. Supposing that the land owner has no legal right to copyright, is it illegal to post this sign?

Edit:
I showed this to an attorney friend this morning and he said "kind of like trying to copyright air".

Comment: The "poor" writing (poor in what, being as clear as possible? it's entirely grammatical compared with most signs) is not evidence of being drafted by a non-legal professional.

Comment: Of course, you making a copy of the *sign* probably infringes copyright in the sign.

Comment: @DaleM : what makes you think so? Something very short and very common cannot usually be copyrighted, especially if it has probably been used in that form many times. (I bet this isn't the first copyright notice ever written, using these terms, even if it's not about a land feature.) Otherwise someone could copyright the phrase "hi, how are you?" and sue you every time you use it.

Comment: @Nij the "and" instead of "or" and the totally silly "to avoid copyright infringement" are pretty glaring.

Comment: @vsz it’s not the literary component alone - it’s the artistic elements as well: font choice, the colours, layout, aspect ratio etc.

Comment: If your picture generates unwanted tourism to this private property then the owner might seek out an enforceable sign.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus The owner could post a "No Trespassing" sign but that would not stop people from stopping on the public road to take pictures. Indeed no sign that the owner could post would legally stop that.

Comment: @DaleM Use of the image of the sign as part of this question, for commentary on the sign and its message, is highly likely to be fair use, even if the sign is original enough to be protected by copyright.

Comment: @Nij a "standard" copyright notice includes a year and the name or identifier of the claimed copyright holder. For Example: "Copyright 2010 by XYZ"

Comment: I note that the sign does not claim that the land feature is copyrighted, only that *photos and videos* taken of it may be. Is this intended to scare people off who don't read it correctly?

Comment: @Organic Marble I don't see how to guess what the person who put up the sign intends, except that s/he probably doesn't want people, to take and publish pictures of the feature. Whether that person misunderstands copyright, or understands it but hopes others don't, can not be determined from the info at hand.

Comment: What the sign says is literally true. If somebody takes a photo of the mountain, it may not be published without the permission of the owner of the photo, and doing so infringes copyright. It's an excellent prank sign.

Comment: @hobbs And they list "published" twice.

Comment: @DaleM: Ordinarily I would counter that "no reasonable person would try to enforce copyright in such a sign, even if they legally can." But this person tried to copyright a *mountain*, so it's safe to say they are not a reasonable person.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

1. Who knows. It doesn't matter.
2. [17 USC 102](https://www.copyright.gov/title17/92chap1.html#102) lists the kinds of things protectable by copyright under US law. These are:

> (1) literary works;
> (2) musical works, including any accompanying words;
> (3) dramatic works, including any accompanying music;
> (4) pantomimes and choreographic works;
> (5) pictorial, graphic, and sculptural works;
> (6) motion pictures and other audiovisual works;
> (7) sound recordings; and
> (8) architectural works.

A landscape feature is none of these and is not subject to copyright protection under US law, nor I think under the law of any other country.  The "copyright notice" has no legal effect.

3. 17 USC 120 Specifically prohibits copyright being used to prevent the taking of pictures of a building from a public place. In many countries [Freedom of panorama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedom_of_panorama) (FOP) specifically permits publication of photos taken from public places. Se also [this article on FOP](https://expertphotography.com/freedom-of-panorama-photography/). FOP is an exception to copyright protection, which applies to copyrighted architectural works and publicly posted works of art, such as sculptures. Since landscape features are not copyrightable at all, FOP does not strictly apply to them, but all the arguments for FOP would apply to them even more strongly.

In US Law, particularly under the *Fiest vs Rural* case, only works with original content, created by a person, are protected by copyright. (Other countries generally have similar limits on copyright.) But a feature of the landscape is not the original creation of any person. (If someone carved the landscape into a designed shape, it might be protect able as a sculpture.)

3 and 4. If it were a building, you could take pictures of it from a public place or a private place where you have a legal right to be, under  17 USC 120 . But since a part of the landscape is not protected by copyright at all, this is not really relevant.

5. No under the US First amendment there is generally a right to say even false things. But if the landowner attempts to enforce this "copyright" it would be considered frivolous and any court proceeding would be promptly tossed out. The sign gives the landowner no rights s/he would not otherwise have.

Comment: A landscape feature might qualify as an "architectural work" or "sculptural work" if there's been significant human modification of it.

Comment: @nick012000 According to 17 USC 101: "An “architectural work” is the design of a building as embodied in any tangible medium of expression, including a building, architectural plans, or drawings. " I think there would need to be some enclosed spaced for it to be considerd a "building". 17 USC does not define "sculptural work"

Comment: @nick012000 E.g. Mount Rushmore.

Comment: @nick012000 Just the example I thought of, although that might be out of copyright as a work of the US Federal govt, Or copyright might be held by the artist who designed it. I have not checked its detailed status.

Comment: @Barmar Also Stone Mountain in Georgia, which was apparently made by the same guy as Mount Rushmore, according to the Wikipedia articles I just read on the subject. TIL the guy who made one of the most famous symbols of American patriotism also made a giant memorial for the Confederates, as well.

Comment: @DavidSiegel: Re point (5): Freedom of speech doesn’t exclude falsehoods in general, but there are exceptions for various kinds of “threat” — e.g. in the UK, this seems like it might well fall under “groundless threats of legal proceedings”.  Does the US have no such provisions?

Comment: What are the possible consequences of "groundless threats of legal proceedings" in the UK?

Comment: @Peter LeFanu Lumsdaine  in the US that would be a matter of state law, and would vary by state. I think in most states such an offense would require a message directed to a specific person, not a general notice such as the sign in the question. Sending a cease and desist order might cause a problem, but I'm not sure. That should perhaps be a separate question.

Comment: @AlLelopath: I don’t know in detail about this at all, I just generally remembered the existence of such provisions in the UK, along with the fact that *some* kinds of threats are not protected in the US, and so wanted to hear a bit more detailed justification on (5) than “the first amendment protects false speech”.  I would love to know more myself about how it would apply in this particular case!

Comment: Could this be taken as a condition to pass if the feature is only visible from private land? (obviously it is overstated that they "copyrighted the feature" as they would not be entitled to copyright for photos taken from the air in this analysis)

Comment: @crasic  The landowner may restrict who comes onto the land, and may instruct people who s/he admits not to take pictures, but if they violate such an instruction the landowner does not get copyright. The landowner can ask such a person to leave, and might have an action for breach of contract, depending on the exact agreement.

Comment: There is one more point of interest pertaining to this sign: does the sign work to reduce the number of people taking photos there?  Probably its original intention.  A sign can be untrue but still effective (for an example of this, a sign advising an area is monitored by CCTV, when it isn't).  Unless the sign encourages more people to take photos (in defiance of it), it probably "works" in the sense that *some* people are discouraged, reducing the number of people who take photos.  It is effectively equivalent to a polite request, in that it has no legal truth to it but may still encourage.

Comment: @David, suppose the owner makes a written agreement with anyone given permission to enter that any photographs are considered works for hire (with the permission to enter being the remuneration)? Could that achieve what crasic asked about?

Comment: @tomr that's my thinking too. It reminds me of a "beware the dog" sign in a place without an actual dog present.

Comment: @prl No. Under US law works made for hire are limited to specific categories, which would not include such photos. I suppose a contract, tr4ansferrign thy copyrights to the landowner could be made (there are subtly different results than a work for hire) but I doubt many would sign such an agreement, and it would have to be in writing, not implied.

Comment: This seems reminiscent of the [Freeman on the Land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeman_on_the_land) nonsense.

Answer (score 4):

Now wait just a danged minute. Isn't this simply a joke sign? Read what it says:

> Photos and videos . . . may not be . . . published [etc] . . . without
> the permission of the owner. . .

The sign maker is not referring to the mountain, he/she is referring to the photos. Of course your photos can't be published without your permission. Everybody knows that. The sign is a joke!

The weird guy down the road from my house when I was a kid put up a yellow sign that said

> Caution: Monogoggle area!

I got that joke too!

Comment: You misoverestimate the mindset of rural New Mexico, cityslicker.

Comment: It could be intended as a joke. If "owner" is read as "owner of the copyright" not "owner of the land" the sign is an accurate statement of the law, although who it is supposed to be warning is less than clear.That could be the joke. That is a question of intent, for which there is no evidence at all.